# expected token ‘end of print statement’, got ‘Size’

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2, data-analysis, docxtpl

I am trying to automate population of word template using python. The library I am using is docxtpl to help me do that. I am getting this expected token ‘end of print statement’ got ‘Size’ error and don’t know where to look for help. It’s some sort of jinja2 error which I haven’t come across before. Any help will be much appreciated.

The code is below:

```
import jinja2

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from jinja2 import Template

doc= DocxTemplate(path to the doc)

context= {“name”:”ABCD”}

doc.render(context)

doc.save(populated_template.docx)
```

Tried the above and many other solutions and nothing has worked. Stuck on this issue for hours. Have installed and uninstalled packages to help alleviate the issue but with no luck.

```
Full traceback below: 
TemplateSyntaxError          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-20a405221771> in <module>
----> 1 doc.render(context)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py in render(self, context, jinja_env, autoescape)
    341 
    342         # Body
--> 343         xml_src = self.build_xml(context, jinja_env)
    344 
    345         # fix tables if needed

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py in build_xml(self, context, jinja_env)
    288         xml = self.get_xml()
    289         xml = self.patch_xml(xml)
--> 290         xml = self.render_xml_part(xml, self.docx._part, context, jinja_env)
    291         return xml
    292 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py in render_xml_part(self, src_xml, part, context, jinja_env)
    243                 exc.docx_context = map(lambda x: re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', x),
    244                                        src_xml.splitlines()[line_number:(line_number + 7)])
--> 245             raise exc
    246         dst_xml = re.sub(r'\n<w:p([ >])', r'<w:p\1', dst_xml)
    247         dst_xml = (dst_xml

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py in render_xml_part(self, src_xml, part, context, jinja_env)
    236                 template = jinja_env.from_string(src_xml)
    237             else:
--> 238                 template = Template(src_xml)
    239             dst_xml = template.render(context)
    240         except TemplateError as exc:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py in __new__(cls, source, block_start_string, block_end_string, variable_start_string, variable_end_string, comment_start_string, comment_end_string, line_statement_prefix, line_comment_prefix, trim_blocks, lstrip_blocks, newline_sequence, keep_trailing_newline, extensions, optimized, undefined, finalize, autoescape, enable_async)
   1029             enable_async,
   1030         )
-> 1031         return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
   1032 
   1033     @classmethod

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py in from_string(self, source, globals, template_class)
    939         globals = self.make_globals(globals)
    940         cls = template_class or self.template_class
--> 941         return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
    942 
    943     def make_globals(self, d):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py in compile(self, source, name, filename, raw, defer_init)
    636             return self._compile(source, filename)
    637         except TemplateSyntaxError:
--> 638             self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
    639 
    640     def compile_expression(self, source, undefined_to_none=True):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py in handle_exception(self, source)
    830         from .debug import rewrite_traceback_stack
    831 
--> 832         reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
    833 
    834     def join_path(self, template, parent):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     26     def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
     27         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 28             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     29         raise value
     30 
<unknown> in template()

TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'Size'
```

Comment: I don't see `Size` anywhere. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You also have the wrong kind of quotes in the `context` dictionary. Is that in the real code or a copying error? Remember to turn off "smart quotes" when pasting code.

Comment: There is no “size” in traceback, not that I could see. Also, copying error in the code. It should be single quotes but that doesn’t do anything at all. The error remains the same.

Comment: Size is probably a jinja template placeholder reference. I am also stuck on the same sort of problem. It seems that a placeholder containing spaces is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your traceback is telling you that one of the placeholders in you document contains spaces. Example:

```
{{ hello world }}
```

Should be:

```
{{ hello_world }}
```